# shape of model is different after loading it to the project

Tags: opengl, glut

I've got `Barrack.obj` object with `Barrack.mtl` file. Also there are several `.tga` files.
I want to load this object to my opengl project.
In order to do this I parse `.obj` and `.mtl` files. And then draw model and set materials like this(method `draw` in model object)

```
for(int g = 0; g < faces.size(); g++)
{
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, materials[g].Ks);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, materials[g].Kd);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, materials[g].Ka);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, materials[g].Ns);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    for(int f = 0; f < faces[g].size(); f++)
    {
        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].z);

        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].z);

        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].z);
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

`normals`,`materials` and etc. are arrays with data from `.mtl` and `.obj` files. `ks, kd, ka, ns` the same values from `.mtl` file. 
In debugger it seems all arrays(vectors) with data from files filled correctly. But object has some strangle `peaks` on the roof.
[image]

I initialize `glut` like this

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
glutCreateWindow("LOADER");
reshape(screenWidth, screenHeight);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

if(!model.load("Barrack.obj"))
{
    cout << "Could not load model" << endl;
    return false;
}

glutDisplayFunc(draw);
```

Where function `draw`

```
void draw()
{
glPushMatrix();

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glCallList(g_persp);

gluLookAt(  0, 3, 3,    //  eye pos
            0, 0, 0,    //  aim point
            0, 1, 0);   //  up direction

glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
model.draw(); // method draw mentioned earlier

glCallList(g_ortho);

glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

**What is the problem? Why there are peaks on the roof?**
In assimpviewer model looks like this
[image]

Reshape function

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
if(h == 0) 
{
    h = 1;
}

screenWidth = w;
screenHeight = h;

glDeleteLists(g_persp, 1);
glDeleteLists(g_ortho, 1);

glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

g_persp = glGenLists(1);
g_ortho = glGenLists(1);

glNewList(g_persp, GL_COMPILE);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45, (float)w / h, 0.1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

glEndList();

glNewList(g_ortho, GL_COMPILE);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -100, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

glEndList();
}
```

Comment: You need to bind and load the texture!

Comment: yeah. my bad. I forgot to do this. so I changed the question

Comment: By changing the title to "strange looking object after loading", well now it's not really a question anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just construction polygons used for some calculations by the designer of the model. They are most probably flagged invisible in the obj file and you just need to filter them out when loading the model if you have access to the loading code.

Comment: how those flags look like?

Comment: search for shadow_obj or trace_obj : http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/txt/obj_format.txt

Comment: If not, I'd look for a perfectly transparent material or texture

Comment: It just occurred to me that the strange peaks might just be vents that are in a separate group and that your program assimpviewer just displays the first group